# Attendees' ResponseStatus in Calendar Event always 'Unknown'

Tags: calendar, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I create an event with a [CreateItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563797(v=exchg.150).aspx)-request with a [CalendarItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/aa564690(v=exchg.150).aspx), assigning myself and `example@domain.onmicrosoft.com` as required attendees.

`example@domain.onmicrosoft.com` then accepts the invitation in his calendar, and I get an email saying that he has accepted.

I later get this event with a [FindItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx)-request with a `CalendarView` present in the request asking for the id of the events, and then use a [GetItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/aa564509(v=exchg.150).aspx)-request to get all its properties. It then says that all the attendees' `ResponseStatus` is `Unknown`.

How do I get the real attendees' `ResponseStatus`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FindItem doesn't return the Attendee responses so you would need to be making a GetItem Call on each Appointment to get the information in that property. (And this would only work on the Copy of the Appointment in the Organizers Mailbox)

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This was not the issue though. I find the calendar event, get it and the status of the attendees are unknown still (even though I'm the organizer).

Comment: Have the attendee responses been processed back into the appointment ? I would suggest you use a Mapi editor like OutlookSpy of MFCMapi and check the recipient collection of the appointment you can then see if the response have been processed.